# How do I put a previous result into the next query? MYSQL

Tags: mysql, syntax, subquery

Okay so, this is my query.

```
select id from rooms where owner = 'oknow';
```

and the answer I get is

```
325
```

However, I made another SQL within this one as below

```
update users set home_room = 'mysql_fetch_assoc()' where username = 'omarisgod';
```

I want the 'mysql_fetchassoc()' to be the '325' value, how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A subquery will do this:

```
UPDATE users SET home_room = (SELECT id FROM rooms WHERE owner = 'oknow') WHERE username = 'omarisgod';
```

You can conceptualize it thusly:  The query inside parentheses will return a result, which will be utilized by the outer query.